# Need to find out children div's from parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am struggling to calculate the length of the children div's, from the parent class name if there are same parent class names.i.e., example is

```
<div class="main-div">
   <div class="parent">
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my code I want to calculate length of the child div's separately from each parent div but i am getting total of whole child class divs i.e, I want to calculate only first parent class children then output will be 4 but I am getting 8. I need to vary them separately and find the length.

my jquery is

```
var countdiv = $('.parent').children('.child').length;
if( countdiv > 1 ){
   something here ..
}
```

Comment: try read up on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each` function

```
$('.parent').each(function(){
    var countDiv = $(this).children('.child').length;
    // do something here
});
```

Live demo [here](https://codepen.io/khanhvdv/pen/MrxJEX)

More information on `.each` function can be found [here](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate *parent* `div`s

```js
$( "div.parent" ).each( function(){
  console.log( "number of children for " + $( this ).index() + "th parent div is " + $( this ).children( ".child" ).length )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-div">
   <div class="parent">
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this selector to get the 1st child:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var countdiv = $('.main-div .parent:first-child').children('.child').length;
  alert(countdiv);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-div">
   <div class="parent">
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```